# stopping scrolling when mini cart is opened on woodmart theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

In woodmart theme when mini cart is open the main page is moving but not fix!
So I want to stop scrolling when mini cart is opened.
When the user opens the cart overlay as mini cart on woodmart, scrolling of the background shouldn't be possible. I have searched and i can't seem to find a workable way around it.
Any help is appreciated.
My code so far

```
  // Get references to the necessary elements/
  const miniCartElement = document.querySelector('.wd-close-side wd-fill wd-close-side-opened');
  const bodyElement = document.body;

  // Function to handle the scroll behavior/
  function handleScrolling(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  }

  // Function to enable/disable scrolling
  function toggleScrolling(enableScrolling) {
  if (enableScrolling) {
    bodyElement.classList.remove('no-scroll');
    bodyElement.removeEventListener('touchmove', handleScrolling);
    } else {
    bodyElement.classList.add('no-scroll');
    bodyElement.addEventListener('touchmove', handleScrolling, { passive: false });
   }
    }

   // Event listener to toggle scrolling when the mini cart is opened/closed
    miniCartElement.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const isOpen = miniCartElement.classList.contains('open');

   // Toggle scrolling based on the mini cart's open/closed state
    toggleScrolling(!isOpen);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily).

Also I think the miniCartElement querySelector is missing the class dots.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I add dots and check the link that you mentioned it but It does not working yet.

Comment: Can you provide a little more info? Did you get the right element now you fixed the dots in your miniCartElement querySelector? Did the no-scroll class got added to the body?

Comment: yes please see this screenshot:

https://s8.uupload.ir/files/screenshot_2023-06-28_at_15-36-33_woodmart_-_multipurpose_woocommerce_theme_wordpress_r823.png

I want disable scrolling  without any moving when minicart is opened.

Comment: If you need woodmart theme for testing or want to see the source of theme file please let me know to give it to you.

Comment: Add a console.log to see if miniCartElement is the element you expect. If so, check your browser inspector to see if the body element gets the no-scroll class when miniCartElement is open. try to narrow the problem by console logging.